# is there a Roslyn API for a webbrowser?

Tags: javascript, html, roslyn

What I am looking for is a an api that load a DOM and javascript and treat it in the manner of   Roslyn.  I can then use to analyze and convert different html into a compliant html 5 with jquery for example???

Roslyn for  javascript would be awesome in of itself. Does it exist?

Answer (score 1):

Roslyn only supports C# and VB. We don't analyze JavaScript or HTML.